# How to implement a nested TabBarView cleanly/correctly?

Tags: flutter

#### Problem:

I am trying to implement nested TabBarView, and succeed in doing so. However, I am not quite sure is this the 'clean' way to write Flutter code.

Everything works well if I just put all widget in one state class. To be more modular, I separate the inner TabBarView from the outer TabBarView. However, I discover that the innerTabController must reside in the outer TabBarView class, in order for the inner TabBarView to recover its previous index correctly.

I consider this as bad code as my outer TabBarView will need to concern about the inner TabBarView details (length, initialIndex, ...)

```
class _TestAppState extends State<TestApp>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController _tabController;
  TabController _innerTabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      vsync: this
    );
    _tabController.addListener(handleTabChange);
    _innerTabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      vsync: this
    );
  }
```

#### Question:

How should I structure the code to make it more clean/maintainable/modular?
Or should I use other method to retain the index of the inner TabView?

#### Code:

https://gist.github.com/HengJunXi/ae99777df6fc5f902805628b3e270ab4

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a better way to do this nested tab bar view thing by using the ValueKey and PageStorageBucket readState() and writeState() methods.

```
  final _tabKey = ValueKey('tab');

  TabController _innerTabController;

  void handleTabChange() {
    print('Inner tab, previous: ${_innerTabController.previousIndex}, current: ${_innerTabController.index}');
    PageStorage.of(context).writeState(context, _innerTabController.index, identifier: _tabKey);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('init');
    int initialIndex = PageStorage.of(context).readState(context, identifier: _tabKey);
    _innerTabController = TabController(
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
      initialIndex: initialIndex != null ? initialIndex : 0
    );
    _innerTabController.addListener(handleTabChange);
  }
```

All of these codes will stay in the inner tab view class, hence the outer tab view class will no longer need to concern about the inner one.

**Full code here:** https://gist.github.com/HengJunXi/b23994fbcb22f0a832dc5c6a50434725